AWS API Gateway Integration responseTemplate
I am using openapi 3.0 to construct my APIGW endpoints, my APIGW calling the ECS Fargat service health endpoint (/actuator/health). When I see "status" : "UP", I am trying to change the "$context.responseOverride.status" and adding new fields. Issue is always am getting "$input.path('$') as empty. When I use "$input.json('$')" getting object value not the text format value, "$input.json('$').toString()" not helping etting same object value."$input.body" prints object.
/sample:
  get:
    response:
     "200":
       content:
         application/json:
           schema:
             $ref: "some component"  
    x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
      timeoutInMillis: 29000
      uri : "https://<<ECS Fargate Service Endpoint>>/actuator/health"
      type: "HTTP"
      httpMethod: "GET"
      connectionType: "VPC_LINK"
      connection_id: <<some value>>
      passthroughBehaviour: "when_no_match"
      response:
        default:
          statusCode: "200"
          responseTemplates:
            application/json: "#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))\n{\n\"status\":\"TEST\"\n}"
            contentHandling: "CONVERT_TO_TEXT"


Try this with simple quote and escaping double quotes inside the string
'#set($inputRoot = $input.path($))\n{\n\"status\":\"TEST\"\n}'

